# Need Help Writing code to find Capparelli Partitions

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, partitions

I am trying to add multiple criterion to

```
IntegerPartitions[n]
```

so that it sorts only partitions that fit the criterion. It creates a list of list of numbers in descending orders and I want to eliminate all the ones that don't fit

- Has no part smaller than `s` (Already Solved)
- part `s` occurs at most `k` times (Already Solved)
- If elements are `Dist` apart then they are at least `Diff` apart
  i.e `list[[i]] - list[[i+Dist]] >= Diff` (Already Solved)
- If parts are a distance `d` from each other and they are within `c` of other
  i.e  if `list[[i]] - list[[i + d]] <= c`
  then the sum of the parts between them (and the parts themselves) is 'm' mod 'M'

I can do some individual conditions like getting part `s` to occur no more than `k` times, but I have trouble getting it to check all these conditions. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks to LLlAMnYP for helping me get as far as I have. Now i have a list of list of integers in descending order and would just like to to filter out all the ones that don't fit the following criterion

- If parts are a distance `d` from each other and they are within `c` of other
  i.e  if `list[[i]] - list[[i + d]] <= c`
  then the sum of the parts between them (and the parts themselves) is 'm' mod 'M'

Comment: Any given partition must satisfy these criteria or the entire set of possible partitions (I mean part `s` occurring no more than `n` times)? The `n` in `IntegerPartitions[n]` is not the same as the limit for number of occurrences of part `s`? Please show how you managed to get the `s` and `n` part of the task to work.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I have also formatted your post, please check if I have not distorted any intent (e.g. changed the sign of inequality for the last criterion, as you say, it should be *within* `c`). Apart from that, I've changed `C` and `D` to lowercase, as both of these in uppercase are reserved symbols in Mathematica.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP, no the the n in IntegerPartitions[n] is not the same as the limit for number of occurrences of part s. sorry about that. I do not have the file where i had those two working on me put i will post it in a few hours when am at that computer. The way i went about it was counting the number of occurences of the element in the list and then removing elements less then the value desired. I assumed that i could use this as an index once the code was working better

Comment: @LLlAMnYP also thanks for the formatting help that makes my post a lot more readable and you got all the info right by the looks of it

Comment: *"If elements are `Dist` apart, they are at least `Diff` apart"*. What if they're more than `Dist` apart?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP If they are more then `Dist` apart then they at least `Dist` apart meaning that they need to be >=. So more than still fits the criteria. sorry if that was unclear hope that clears it up

Comment: I see. My answer does not consider that yet. I'll see what I come up with later, but for now I have to go afk.

Comment: Don't worry about the third criterion i have that one solved now all i need is the fourth

Comment: @StephenHill upon further consideration, I realized, that since the sequence of numbers is decreasing, then if numbers at distance `dist` are `diff` apart, then numbers at bigger distances are also at least `diff` apart. Regarding the last criterion, I'll try to come up with something tomorrow, once I'm at work.

Comment: *the sum of the parts between them (and the parts themselves) is 'm' mod 'M'* Just to avoid confusion, that means, that the remainder of dividing this sum by `M` is `m`, right?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP thanks man that is what I mean, it should have a certain remainder when divided by a number. A small problem I should be able to remedy myself is that your condition  3 check eliminates all list with less then dist elements. I can readd them with some sort of Union command probably so not big deal. Thanks again for all your help

Answer (score 2):

Here's my implementation of satisfying the first two conditions.

```
capPartitions[n_Integer, s_Integer, k_Integer] := 
 Flatten[Table[
   Join[ConstantArray[s, i], #] & /@ 
    Select[IntegerPartitions[n - i s], AllTrue[#, # < s &] &],
    {i, k, 0, -1}], 1]
```

Not extremely efficient, rather generates more possible partitions than necessary, then filters the bad ones out.

Here's a function, that tests a list of numbers for satisfying the third condition:

```
testDiff = 
 AllTrue[Subtract @@ (Partition[#, Length@# - #2, #2]), 
   Function[{diff}, diff >= #3]] &
```

Usage: `testDiff[partition, dist, diff]`, returns `True` or `False`.

Generate all partitions of 15 where 4 occurs no more than 3 times:

```
capPartitions[15, 4, 3];
```

Filter such, that elements 3 apart differ at least by 2:

```
Select[%, testDiff[#, 3, 2] &]
```

> ```
> {{4, 4, 4, 2, 1}, {4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 4, 3, 2, 2}, {4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1}}
> ```

Hopefully this should get you started. I'll give the problem some more thought and try to come up with an update. Be warned, I haven't considered error-handling here yet. Mathematica may complain about inappropriate stuff with certain combinations of arguments.

**1st update**
Naturally, as commented under OP, checking the 3rd condition on a partition shorter than `dist` (using my algorithm) means partitioning it into sublists of negative length. So here's a better `testDiff` function, that gives the thumbs-up to any partition that's shorter than `dist` without wasting cpu time for the proper test:

```
testDiff =
 Which[Length@# < #2, True,
   True, AllTrue[Subtract @@ (Partition[#, Length@# - #2, #2]), 
    Function[{diff}, diff >= #3]]] &
```

For the moment a "to-do" remains for the first two conditions. As I said, `capPartitions` is a bit inefficient. Instead of running

```
Select[IntegerPartitions[n - i s], AllTrue[#, # < s &] &]
```

it would be much better to generate here only those partitions of `n - i s` whose biggest addend is smaller than `s`. That means only taking the last `x` partitions, which should be an analytically expressible quantity, but this will need a bit more thought on my part.

**2nd update**
To check the fourth criterion we need to examine each partition that remains after applying the previous criteria. Say, we have a partition of the form

```
{c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9}
```

and we're interested in such sequences, that if two numbers are 4 apart and within, say, 2 of each other...

```
Partition[{c1...c9}, 4 + 1, 1] (* which gives... *)
{{c1, c2, c3, c4, c5},
 {c2, c3, c4, c5, c6},
 {c3, c4, c5, c6, c7},
 {c4, c5, c6, c7, c8},
 {c5, c6, c7, c8, c9}}
```

of which we select only those, where the difference of `First@# - Last@# <= 2 &` to the result of which we apply `Total/@` then `Mod[#, M]/@` then `AllTrue[..., # == m]`... this leads me to roll a function `testMod` which looks like this:

```
testMod = 
 AllTrue[Function[{tot}, Mod[tot, #4]] /@ 
    Total /@ (Select[Partition[#, #2 + 1, 1], 
       Function[{part}, (First@part - Last@part <= #3) && Length@part == #2 + 1]]),
         Function[{mod}, mod == #5]] &
```

`testMod[partition, d, c, M, m]` takes a list of integers (`partition`), and checks, if there are any subsequences, which are of length `d + 1` (if not, the partition is too short and the criterion need not apply) whose first and last element differ by `c` or less, in which case it takes the total of the sequence (each subsequence of length `d + 1`, actually) and divides each total modulo `M`, then runs an `AllTrue` to check if each result is equal to `m`.

Here're the function definitions all in one block for easy copy-paste:

```
capPartitions[n_Integer,s_Integer,k_Integer]:=Flatten[Table[Join[ConstantArray[s,i],#]&/@Select[IntegerPartitions[n-i s],AllTrue[#,#<s&]&],{i,k,0,-1}],1]
testDiff=Which[Length@#<#2,True,True,AllTrue[Subtract@@(Partition[#,Length@#-#2,#2]),Function[{diff},diff>=#3]]]&
testMod=AllTrue[Function[{tot},Mod[tot,#4]]/@Total/@(Select[Partition[#,#2+1,1],Function[{part},(First@part-Last@part<=#3)&&Length@part>#2]]),Function[{mod},mod==#5]]&
```

Let's generate all Capparelli partitions of 15 with 4 occurring no more than 3 times...

```
capPartitions[15, 4, 3];
```

elements 6 apart must differ by 1...

```
Select[%, testDiff[#, 6, 1] &]
```

if elements are 4 apart and within 2 of each other then their sum plus the sum of those between them modulo 2 must equal 1...

```
Select[%, testMod[#, 4, 2, 2, 1] &]
```

> ```
> {{4, 4, 4, 3}, {4, 4, 4, 2, 1}, {4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1},
>  {4, 4, 3, 3, 1}, {4, 4, 3, 2, 2}, {4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1},
>  {4, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1},
>  {4, 3, 3, 3, 2}, {4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1},
>  {4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2},
>  {3, 3, 3, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1},
>  {3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1}, {3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
> }
> ```

**3rd update**
Apparently, I cannot read (the documentation), because much of the functionality is already coded into the built-in `IntegerPartitions[]` function. Using the 2nd and 3rd argument we can make the `capPartitions[]` function much more efficient.

Let's revisit the OP (and this time I'll do it as he requests, with all addends **not** less than `s`). I also present the `testDiff` and `testMod` functions in a more human-readable form.

```
kMinAddendsS[n_Integer, s_Integer, k_Integer] := 
 Flatten[Table[
   Join[#, ConstantArray[s, i]] & /@ 
    IntegerPartitions[n - i s, All, Range[s + 1, n]], {i, k, 0, -1}], 
  1]

testDiff2[list_List, dist_Integer, diff_Integer] :=
 Which[Length@list < dist + 1, True,
  True, AllTrue[
   Subtract @@ (Partition[list, Length@list - dist, dist]), (# >= 
      diff &)]]

testMod2[list_List, d_, c_, M_, m_] :=
 Which[Length@list < d + 1, True,
  True, And @@ ((# == m &)@*(Mod[#, M] &)@*Total) /@ 
    DeleteCases[_?(First@# - Last@# > c &)]@Partition[list, d + 1, 1]]

capparelliPartitions[n_Integer, s_Integer: 0, k_Integer: 0, 
   dist_Integer: 1, diff_Integer: 0, d_Integer: 1, c_Integer: - 1, 
   M_Integer: 1, m_Integer: 1] /; s <= n/2 && n > 0 && s >= 0 :=
 Module[{partitions = kMinAddendsS[n, s, k]},
  partitions = Select[partitions, testDiff2[#, dist, diff] &];
  partitions = Select[partitions, testMod2[#, d, c, M, m] &]
  ]
```

The `capparelliPartitions` function includes some error handling and takes up to nine arguments. So one can limit himself to just the first condition, or just the first two, etc.

Comment: That works pretty well, except i had a typo in my original question that was minor and i fixed it. I changed it from bigger to smaller in the first condition and all that meant was changing > to < in the fourth line of cappartitions. that is my fault though. thanks for all your help and i will keep working on conditions 3 and 4

Comment: Looking forward to you expanding this, +1

Comment: @StephenHill, ciao, updated. Horrible code, lot's of optimizing to do. Perhaps other contributors would be interested in making this better? Also, I didn't realize until now, that all addends must be *bigger* than `s`. In that case, not only should the inequality be reversed, but also the order of arguments in `Join` to maintain the decreasing order of addends in a partition.

Comment: @StephenHill I've updated again with a more human-readable form and rolled all three functions for satisfying the various conditions into one `Module`. Hope it works.